# Read characters from a single line including whitespaces rather than from a new line

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

IN C# i am trying to solve a problem :
Write a program that checks whether the product of the odd elements is equal to the product of the even elements.

The only thing left is:
 On the second line you will receive N numbers separated by a whitespace.
I am unable to get this working. I have tried with Split but it keeps breaking. Can someone help?

Example:

Input
5
2 1 1 6 3
Output

yes 6

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long N = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    long[] array = new long[N];
    long ODD = 1;
    long EVEN = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
        {
            EVEN *= array[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ODD *= array[i];
        }

    }

    if (EVEN == ODD)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("yes" +  " " +
            ODD);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("no" + " " + ODD + " " + EVEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Split is the right approach. What do you mean with "it keeps breaking"?

Comment: I cant split it because the array is int.

Comment: First split into a string array, then while iterating over this array, convert each element to an int,

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is that I need to take the values as long to give the index of the array first.

            long N = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long[] array = new long[N];

Comment: You only have two lines worth of input. So you should have exactly two Console.ReadLine() calls to read those two lines of input (and not N+1 calls of Console.ReadLine() like your code is doing now)

Comment: @elgonzo the first N is to give the number of N elements of the array. It is necessary. It is not N+1 calls it is exactly the I number of calls because it is  i < N

Comment: I did not say it is unnecessary. Read my comment again carefully.

Comment: However, requiring to input N first is actually unnecessary/redundant in reality. Think about it. If i enter "5 7 8 4 2 1", you know these are 6 numbers. It is easy to see why these are 6 numbers. You would not need to input N explicitly, because this information can be derived from the input "5 7 8 4 2 1". Follow the advice given by Klaus... (But if it makes things simple and easy for you, proceed with inputting N first...)

Comment: @elgonzo 
Do you mean 
long N = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long[] array = new long[N];
                    array[] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
and then do the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read from console input and keep it to an `string` array, 
> Then convert each array element to `long` and apply the `Odd` `Even` logic like below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] inputArray = input.Split(' ');

        long element;
        long odd = 1;
        long even = 1;
        foreach (var i in inputArray)
        {
            element = long.Parse(i);
            if (element % 2 == 0)
            {
                even *= element;
            }
            else
            {
                odd *= element;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nOdd product = " + odd + ", Even product = " + even);

        if (odd == even)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ODD == EVEN \n");

            Console.WriteLine("Yes" + " " + odd);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ODD != EVEN \n");

            Console.WriteLine("No" + " " + odd + " " + even);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long[] nums = input.Split(' ').Select(x => long.Parse(x))..ToArray(); //split numbers by space and cast them as int
int oddProduct = 1, evenProduct = 1; // initial values

foreach(long x in nums.Where(a => a%2 == 1))
    oddProduct *= x;    // multiply odd ones

foreach(long x in nums.Where(a => a%2 == 0))
    evenProduct *= x;   // multiply even ones
```

Comment: Your answer looks good but needs little edit. He used `long` not `int`.

Comment: @bolkay thanks, I hadn't noticed., I edited my answer.  however, it does not make any difference

Comment: I don't understand what that input is?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<long>' to 'long[]' OddorEvenProduct

Comment: @grozdeto sorry i was missing `.ToArray()`. I corrected it. and if you need explanation, we can go to chat.